Would "he had been" be better here?

When the gig was over Johnny's hand had swollen to the size of a catcher's mitt. The patron came over to Johnny, his face cut and swollen, gave Johnny a hug and in his English brogue, said it was the best he'd spent since he'd gotten lost in the USA trying to hitch hike to LA. Apparently, he was a roadie in the travelling troupe known as the Sex Pistols and had gotten separated at an airport on the way across the USA heading for Los Angeles.
John Rokker

Why "was a roadie" and not had been? Because at the time of writing, we can't consider he was still a roadie. We know  he was a roadie until he got separated from the band.
Does the writer consider he is still a roadie at the time of writing?

English brogue? Really? Who wrote this stuff?

I suppose John Rokker

We can say that people have professions or occupations even if they are not employed, either at all, or doing the named work, at the time of speaking. I have met plenty of actors who are either on unemployment benefit or working in pubs. This applies to roadies too.

so he still considers he was a roadie even if he was not working as a roadie

Yves, you got it!

I gather that 'John Rokker' is some kind of American musician.

Yves, 'who wrote this stuff?' is a rhetorical question (one requiring no answer); the real meaning is 'that text is crap'.

The past perfect talks about times before the past.  So to say "he had been a roadie" would imply he was no longer a roadie during the main time line set in the past simple.  This is obviously not what the writer wants to say.

At the time he got lost in the USA he was a roadie.

The simple past is often used with past professions or roles, or when that fact (or another fact) is being presented as the context or explanation for another element of the narrative, and is  not presented as part of the main overarching sequence of events:

I was a DJ in college, so I was able to step in and keep the dancing going at my cousin's wedding when the DJ she hired passed out.

That sentence could be spoken on a Monday about a wedding over the weekend, or it could be spoken years later by an old man telling his grandchildren about memorable moments in his life.
The past perfect places the action in the "distant" past:

... [he left his ID back at the hotel | he needed to visit the rest room | whatever] and had gotten separated at an airport on the way across the USA heading for Los Angeles.

That he forgot his wallet or had to pee could be merely incidental to the story about a concert tour; the tour itself could be the main overarching sequence of events that matters to the storyteller; and so the past perfect could place his separation from the crew relative to the upcoming concert, where his absence was felt.
